# Webpack does not create or update index.asset.php file in build folder

Tags: theme-development, workflow, sass

I am using [@wordpress/scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-scripts/) package to set up Webpack in a WordPress theme. However, I ran into a problem with default Webpack configuration as it is creating an unnecessary .js file inside the build folder for every .scss file that it watches. I found a workaround by using `FixStyleOnlyEntriesPlugin` and `MiniCssExtractPlugin`. Currently, no extra js files are generated inside the build folder but now I ran into another issue - the .asset.php files inside the build folder are no longer generated or updated.

`webpack.config.js`

```
/**
 * External Dependencies
 */
const path = require( 'path' );
const FixStyleOnlyEntriesPlugin = require( 'webpack-fix-style-only-entries' );
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require( 'mini-css-extract-plugin' );

/**
 * WordPress Dependencies
 */
const defaultConfig = require( '@wordpress/scripts/config/webpack.config.js' );

module.exports = {
    ...defaultConfig,
    ...{
        entry: {
            main: path.resolve( process.cwd(), 'assets/sass', 'app.scss' ),
            woocommerce: path.resolve( process.cwd(), 'assets/sass', 'woocommerce.scss' ),
            app: path.resolve( process.cwd(), 'assets/js', 'app.js' ),
        },
    },
    plugins: [ new FixStyleOnlyEntriesPlugin(), new MiniCssExtractPlugin() ],
};
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "my-theme",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A child theme of the Twenty Twenty Two theme",
  "scripts": {
      "build": "wp-scripts build",
      "start": "wp-scripts start",
      "lint:css": "wp-scripts lint-style",
      "lint:js": "wp-scripts lint-js",
      "format:css": "npm run lint:css -- --fix",
      "format:js": "npm run lint:js -- --fix"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
      "@wordpress/scripts": "^24.6.0",
      "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.1",
      "webpack-fix-style-only-entries": "^0.6.1",
      "rtlcss": "^4.0"
  },
  "author": "Atanas Yonkov",
  "license": "GNU GPL"
}
```

Comment: Can you give more information? Your package.json, which files do you consider "unnecessary"?

Comment: Webpack generates js file for every entry, even when it is a .css file. In my case, when I ran `npm run start` the default Webpack config (without the plugins) generates `main.js`, `woocommerce.js`, `main.css`, `woocommerce.css` and `app.js`, while it should only generate `main.css`, `woocommerce.css` and `app.js`

Answer (score 2):

I could not reproduce the issue, however bear in mind that despite

> This is a collection of reusable scripts tailored for WordPress development.

initial sentence in package description, @wordpress/scripts are primarily meant for block development, as block.json are scanned to find entry points. You can also provide entry points yourself, by specifying extra parameter for entry or if your folder is named src. It may depend how your scss is imported (probably from javascript), that in development phase js is created for the purpose of injecting css into the DOM and that is normal. Try invoking build to see if js files disappear.

When I need something that is not block related, I usually set up webpack myself, not relying on @wordpress/scripts. You can as well have several webpack configs in your project and invoking webpack directly and providing specific config as parameter. This also speeds compilation, as I do not compile everything each time, but project is split into chunks. See example below:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@fontsource/red-hat-display": "^4.5.11",
    "@wordpress/scripts": "^24.6.0",
    "accordion-js": "^3.3.2",
    "hamburgers": "^1.2.1",
    "micromodal": "^0.4.10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "viewmodal_development": "webpack --mode=development --watch --config ./webpack-viewmodal.config.js",
    "viewmodal_production": "webpack --mode=production --node-env production --config ./webpack-viewmodal.config.js",
    "blocks_build": "wp-scripts build --webpack-src-dir=./src/blocks",
    "blocks_start": "wp-scripts start --webpack-src-dir=./src/blocks",
    "blocks_hot": "wp-scripts start --webpack-src-dir=./src/blocks --hot",
    "packages-update": "wp-scripts packages-update"
  }
}
```

If you need, you can as well add script configuration to invoke more than one task from above, using package *concurrently* or similar.

EDIT: if you only need scss compiled, I would set up standalone scss compiler, as it is faster than node compilers and setup a task in your editor/IDE - I use VSCode and I added this to tasks.json for compiling scss:

```
{
            "label": "sassify build",
            "type": "shell",
            "group": "build",
            "command": "sass",
            "windows": {
                "command": "sass src\\hamburger\\slider.scss assets\\css\\hamburger.css"
            },
            "options": {
                "env": {
                    "PATH": "C:/Noinstall Programs/dart-sass"
                }
            },
            "runOptions": {
                "instanceLimit": 1
            }
        }
```